# TextView displaying text in One line when adding rows programatically in Table Layout

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a table layout after some view in my xml file. Below is the code.

```
<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>

..................................
.....................................
<Button
         android:id="@+id/fetchbutton"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="show details"
         android:layout_margin="6dip"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:onClick="buttonOnClick"/>

         <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/mytable_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
             >
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Below is the code to add the rows programatically for a table layout:**

```
public void buttonOnClick(View view)
    {
        showData();
    }
    public void showData()
    {

        List<DataSource> data = dbHelper.getData(selectedoption);
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.mytable_layout);

        for(DataClass dataclass:data)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(ViewScreen.this);

            TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            tr.setLayoutParams(params);   

            TextView labelTV = new TextView(ViewScreen.this);
            labelTV.setText(dataclass.getColumnName());
            labelTV.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            TableRow.LayoutParams paramsTV1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            labelTV.setLayoutParams(paramsTV1);
            tr.addView(labelTV);

            // Creating a TextView to house the value of the after-tax income
            TextView valueTV = new TextView(ViewScreen.this);
            valueTV.setText(dataclass.getColumnValue());
            valueTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            TableRow.LayoutParams paramsTV2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            valueTV.setLayoutParams(paramsTV2);
            tr.addView(valueTV);

            // Adding the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        }

    }
```

So as per the above code, it's working fine. But the table row is always with one line. The `table row height` is not `increased` according to the content. Instead the part of text goes off screen and invisible. Can some one please help to solve this issue?

**Picture:**

[image]

Comment: android:orientation="vertical" no of this

Comment: I didn't include this android:orientation="vertical" at first. So, I just gave a try by adding this. It didn't work in both cases.

Comment: Can you display the screenshot please.

Comment: Added screenshot too for better explanation.

Comment: You have to provide fixed width and height to wrap_content to the TextView in Black color. Hope this might be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean? fixing width and height to wrap_content? If your intention is to suggest applying fixed width and height in dps to textviews, it is not recommended at all. Because what if the text exceeds the given width/height as the text length is unknown.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

create a custom single_row.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutSingleRowRecordsDetailedView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSingleRowRecordsDetailedViewCategoryField"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#04B4AE"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSingleRowRecordsDetailedViewCategoryFieldValue"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then in my java code:

```
...
LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.single_row_records_detailed_view, null);

                TextView tv_field_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleRowRecordsDetailedViewCategoryField);
                TextView tv_field_value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleRowRecordsDetailedViewCategoryFieldValue);

                if(al_field_value.get(i).equals(""))
                {
                    null_count = null_count + 1;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    tv_field_name.setText(get_field_name(al_cat_field_id.get(i)));
                    tv_field_value.setText(al_field_value.get(i));
                }

                linearLayout_details.addView(view);
...
```

Comment: Please read my question clearly. If I use this linear layout params, the views will not be visible at all. Even if I apply these params to my textview like TableRow.LayoutParams paramsTV1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(150, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            labelTV.setLayoutParams(paramsTV1); It doesn't work either. My problem is that height of the row doesn't get increased along with the content.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not able to understand why my previous answer is not able to solve your problem. Sorry for that, but you can definitely go for customizing the layout. check my edited answer. Wait for moment please. I want to show what i did to achieve the same as you want.

Comment: I can't hardcode :( Is there any other way so that it shouldn't use android:layout_width="120dp" ?

Comment: I dont think you have to do much more code to apply my fix. But i can assure you, you will achieve your desired output. Thats for sure. And Don't be so static, be dynamic. You can just give it a try atleast. First try the way your helpers show you, and when you are done achieving your goal, try finding why it wasn't happening with your previous code. This is how you learn. Mark my words.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your Textview multiline.

add below lines to your code to make textview multiline.

```
yourtextview.setSingleLine(false);
```

hope this helps

Comment: @Ark : did you tried setting both params to wrap_contents,give it a try with multiline

Comment: Checked with that too. No use. Is my code working on your side? I am sure it doesn't :( Don't know what's wrong, please help with another.

Answer (score 0):

set the following to your tablelayout:-

```
tablename.setColumnShrinkable(ColumnIndex, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the shrinkable attribute of the tablelayout to get the effect you want. the document from Android developer website :

> The width of a column is defined by the row with the widest cell in
>   that column. However, a TableLayout can specify certain columns as
>   shrinkable or stretchable by calling setColumnShrinkable() or
>   setColumnStretchable(). If marked as shrinkable, the column width can
>   be shrunk to fit the table into its parent object. If marked as
>   stretchable, it can expand in width to fit any extra space. The total
>   width of the table is defined by its parent container. It is important
>   to remember that a column can be both shrinkable and stretchable. In
>   such a situation, the column will change its size to always use up the
>   available space, but never more. Finally, you can hide a column by
>   calling setColumnCollapsed().

example :

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_print_job_detail_info_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="1"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/image_button_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner_white_background_shape" >
```